# Invert probabilities (lowest value to have the highest probability in a set)

Tags: probability

I have a set of values $(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$ positive integers. I want to assign probabilities depending on the value, with the lowest having the highest probability. The sum of probabilities should be $1$ for the whole set.

I can do it the other way around if I find $t = \sum v_i$ then $p(v_i) = \frac{v_i}{t}$ but the lowest value has the least probability.

Answer (score 2):

For any finite set $\mathcal V = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n\}$, you simply need to define
$$p_i = g(v_i)$$
where $g(\cdot)$ is any function such that

- $g(v) > 0$ for all $v \in \mathcal V$
- $x < y$ implies that $g(x) > g(y)$ (monotonicity)

Then you can define the probability mass function
$$p(v) = \begin{cases}
\frac{v_i}{\sum_{u\in\mathcal V}g(u)}, & v = v_i \in \mathcal V \\
0, & v \notin \mathcal V
\end{cases}$$

Two simple functions with this property are
$$g_1(v) = q^v, \ q \in (0,1)$$
and
$$g_2(v) = v^{-s}, \ s > 0.$$
For $\mathcal V = \mathbb N$, these functions correspond to the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and [Zipfs law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law) (when $s > 1$) respectively. The process described above truncates the distribution to a finite set of values.

Also note that $\mathcal V$ can be countably infinite by requiring

- $\sum_{v\in\mathcal V}g(v) < \infty$

---

As a concrete example, suppose that the set of positive integers is $\{3, 5, 8, 16\}$ and you choose Zipfs law with $s=1$. Then
$$p_t \propto \begin{cases}
1/3, &t=1 \\
1/5, &t=2 \\
1/8, &t=3 \\
1/16, &t=4
\end{cases}$$
which gives probabilities
$$P(V=v) = \begin{cases}
0.4624, &v=3 \\
0.2775, &v=5 \\
0.1734, &v=8 \\
0.0867, &v=16 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: can the geometric distribution method be used on a set of random integers like the example for Zipfs law?

Comment: Yes of course, you just need to select a parameter $p$. I can't give any advice on that without more information. In the example above, choosing $p=1/2$ gives probabilities $0.7804, 0.1951, 0.0244, 0.0001$.